# Loopback + elastic beanstalck deploy error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, loopback

i am trying to deploy a Loopback app to Elastic Beanstalck, and i am having this error. Could you help me trying to know what is happening?

Thanks a lot.

```
+ eb deploy app-production
WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
Creating application version archive "app-9d60-170636_164900".
Uploading appEnvironment/app-9d60-170636_164900.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
INFO: Environment update is starting.
INFO: Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Info. Application update in progress (running for 10 seconds).
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
ERROR: Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
ERROR: [Instance: i-00aber9f1456rc341] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED).../opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
    raise e
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-00abbf9f1322cc780'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

Comment: I have the same problem. This is my config: image: `node:6.9.4

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
            - npm install
            #- npm test
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-dev
            - curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
            - python get-pip.py
            - pip install awsebcli --upgrade
            - eb init apimasdados -r eu-west-1 -p node.js
            - eb deploy masdados-production`

Answer (score 0):

In the Elastic Beanstalk Console click on "Logs". Then request the last 100 lines and have a look there. If there is an issue with one of the installed packages, then you find the information there.
For me there was a problem with the bcrypt package. I removed it and everything worked.